# Attempt to remove last type from a tuple is failing

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to remove the last element of a tuple. It works when I have only one element in the tuple to remove. But when I have more than one, things go wrong. I can't get why this isn't working. These are the errors I'm getting:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘`int main()`’:
>   prog.cpp:24:22: error: incomplete type ‘`remove_last<std::tuple<int, int> >`’ used in nested name specifier
>   prog.cpp:24:22: error: incomplete type ‘`remove_last<std::tuple<int, int> >`’ used in nested name specifier
>   prog.cpp:24:70: error: template argument 1 is invalid

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct remove_last;

template <class T>
struct remove_last<std::tuple<T>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

template <class... Args, typename T>
struct remove_last<std::tuple<Args..., T>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, int> var;

    static_assert(
        std::is_same<remove_last<decltype(var)>::type,
        std::tuple<int>>::value, "Values are not the same"
    );
}
```

The errors go away when I make the template argument non-variadic in one of the specializations. But then that becomes a specialization which will only process a tuple with two elements - not what I was aiming for. How can I get this to work *with* variadic arguments? In other words, how can I get this to work when there is more than one element in the tuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the argument pack is greedy and - since it comes first - eats up all the types in the sequence when performing type deduction, including the `T` you expect to be left out of `Args...`.

You could define the variadic specialization this way (notice that the argument pack is now appearing *last* in `std::tuple<T, Args...>`):

```
template <class T, class... Args>
struct remove_last<std::tuple<T, Args...>>
{
    using type = typename concat_tuple<
        std::tuple<T>,
        typename remove_last<std::tuple<Args...>>::type
        >::type;
};
```

And have the `concat_tuple` meta-function defined this way:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct concat_tuple { };

template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Ts..., Us...>;
};
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Why *"the argument pack is greedy"* doesn't apply to the specialization of `concat_tuple`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Because the number of type arguments of `concat_tuples` is fixed

Comment: I don't understand the recursive part. Can you explain to me how is this removing the last element?

Comment: @Andy: I don't see that as difference. Even in `remove_last`, number of type argument is fixed.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Suppose you have a tuple of N elements t1, t2, ..., tN. The algorithm works by creating a one-element tuple t1 and concatenating that with `remove_last<std::tuple<t2, t3, ..., tN>>::type`. That will in turn concatenate `tuple<t2>` with `remove_last<std::tuple<t3, ..., tN>>::type`, and so on. So in the end you will get a concatenation of `tuple<t1>`, `tuple<t2>`, `tuple<t3>`... up to `tuple<t(N-1)>`, because of the base step

Comment: @Nawaz: OK, but that's different, because inside `tuple< ... >` the OP has an argument pack expansion first and *then* a `T`. It's like trying to call a variadic function template that has a variadic parameter expansion first and then an additional argument

Comment: But I still don't see how it excludes the last element. I'm trying hard to visualize it, but I fail. :(

Comment: @0x499602D2: It excludes the last element because of the base case `template <class T> struct remove_last<std::tuple<T>>`, which defines `type` as `std::tuple<>`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution, requires C++14 or newer:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class Tuple>
struct remove_last;

template<>
struct remove_last<std::tuple<>>; // Define as you wish or leave undefined

template<class... Args>
struct remove_last<std::tuple<Args...>>
{
private:
    using Tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;

    template<std::size_t... n>
    static std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<n, Tuple>...>
        extract(std::index_sequence<n...>);

public:
    using type = decltype(extract(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - 1>()));
};

template<class Tuple>
using remove_last_t = typename remove_last<Tuple>::type;
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence